# Probability of a specific outcome separated by certain number of trials

Tags: probability, statistics

Hope this question does not fall under the homework question criteria.

The probability of a particular outcome (say Outcome-X) is 1 in 6200 (or say one in n) trials. If 877 million (or say N) trials are conducted, how many instances of (exactly two consecutive Outcome-X) should be expected per the probability?

Next level - how many instances of (two Outcome-X just one trial apart) should be expected per the probability? Means, get Outcome-X in a trial, then get any other outcome in next trial, and get Outcome-X in next trial again.

Basically, what is the expected number of instances where two Outcome-X are separated by a gap of g outcomes which are different from Outcome-X. Here g can be 0, 1, 2..

Comment: Whether a question is "homework" or not is not the issue, but rather, whether we see indications of effort taken to solve the problem; that is to say, context.  Showing one's efforts provides insight into how much mathematical knowledge the asker has, thus allows those who write answers to target their response to an appropriate level.

Comment: It benefits the Asker of a Question to provide context so Readers can respond at a level which meets their own level of understanding.  Before tackling such a problem I would want to know (for example) if the poster was familiar with probability at the level of Bernoulli trials or transition matrices.

Comment: Please show some of your *own work*!  Demonstrate what efforts have you made to solve the problem, what you know about it, and where have you gotten stuck.  People are more likely (and better able) to help when they see how you have helped yourself.

Comment: @heropup: I am not familiar a lot with the subject at the time, even though I studied the subject in masters. I do think the formulation should be easy for someone who knows the subject. The actual calculations seem challenging.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: please see above.

Comment: @hardmath: please see above.

Comment: Even with a limited background (or recall) of solution methods, you can add to the context what makes the problem interesting, or what limited cases you know how to solve.  This sort of thing also helps you to realize when your description of what is to be counted (or assigned a probability) is imprecise.  For example, does a sequence `XXoXXooXX` count as one success or as two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $N$ trials, there are $N-1$ pairs of consecutive trials.  If they are independent trials with probability $p$ of success in each one, the probability that both members of a given pair are successes is $p^2$, so the expected number of pairs of consecutive trials that are both successes is $(N-1)p^2$.

Similarly, if you ask how many pairs of successes separated by $m$ failures, 
there are $N-m-1$ possible pairs, with probability $p^2 (1-p)^m$ for each one,
so expected number $(N-m-1) p^2 (1-p)^m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and simple. Just to make sure I understood clearly and it is not too simple to be true, probability of two consecutive successes would be (877 million - 1)/(6200*6200). Is this correct?

Comment: Not the probability, the expected number.  In this case, $(877\times 10^6)/(6200^2) \approx 22.815$.

Comment: Thank you. If there is a quick to calculate formula for probability, or,  expected number of instances of (m or more) consecutive failures. Same scenario, i.e. (877 M trials,  p (success) = 1 in 6205).

Comment: Hi Robert, never mind, I will ask it as a new question with little more description. Thanks

Comment: Could you please answer/improve this questiom - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888887/easily-calculable-minimum-probability-for-m-or-more-consecutive-outcomes