# Easily calculable minimum probability for m or more consecutive outcomes

Tags: probability, statistics

I have to calculate probability for m or more consecutive outcomes in a set of trials. The number of trials (N) is very large. There are only two outcomes O1 and O2. Probability p of O1 is 6204 in 6205 and probability of O2 is (1-p). Hence, probability of O1 is very large as compared to that of O2. The trials are independent.

I have to calculate the probability of (m or more) consecutive O1 outcomes.

I looked online and the formula/calculations are pretty complicated.

But I do not need the exact probability. If I can get bulk of it, will do for me. All I have to do, is to establish a minimum probability keeping the calculations simple.

So, I thought of adding following for my purpose -

First m outcomes can be all O1 followed by O2, with probability = $p^m$(1-p).

First m+1 outcomes can be all O1 followed by O2, with probability = $p^1p^m$(1-p).

First m+2 outcomes can be all O1 followed by O2, with probability = $p^2p^m$(1-p).

and so on ... and add them in the end.

If I continue this way, after some iterations, the values become so insignificantly small that it does not matter whether I continue further or stop there. But by that time, I have already achieved the minimum value I need to establish.

Question is - Is there any flaw in this logic for establishing a lower limit of probability for (m or more) consecutive O1s. If so, what is the flaw and what is its fix.

With N being large enough, would it be ok to apply same logic to last m, m+1, m+2 ... to double my lower limit?

Comment: You did not take into account that consecutive $O_1$'s  can occur during the $N$ trials not only at the beginning. And: if $N$ is large then there may occur multiple (separated) consecutive $O_1$ occurrences. (Or are you interested only in consecutive $O_1$'s only at the beginning?)

Comment: $O_1$'s does not need to be followed by $O_2$ since you ask for m ***or more*** consecutives $O_1$. Then the formula for (at least) first m outcomes to $O_1$ is : $p^m$.   Maybe this is already enough for your limit, if you want a higher limit you must consider $O_1$'s series that are not at the begining, as mentionned by @zoli

Comment: @zoli:I mentioned that in the question. I am willing to ignore those that occur not in the begining, or not on the end. The question is - Is the sum of the probabilities I listed is <= the probability of (m or more consecutive O1s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be modelled with a Markov chain with $m+1$ states.   We are in state $i$, $0 \le i \le m-1$, if the preceding $i$ trials were all $O_1$ but we have not yet seen $m$ successive $O_1$'s, or in state $m$ if we have seen $m$ successive $O_1$'s.  Thus we start in state $0$, and at each trial where we are not already in state $m$, if the outcome of the trial is $O_1$ we increase the state by $1$, otherwise we reset it to $0$.  State $m$ is absorbing: once we're there we stay there.  The transition matrix $P$ looks like

$$ \pmatrix{ 1-p & p & 0 &\ldots& 0 & 0\cr
             1-p & 0 & p &\ldots& 0 & 0\cr
             \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \cr
             1-p & 0 & 0 & \ldots& p & 0\cr
             1-p & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & p\cr
              0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1\cr}$$

The probability that we have at least one run of $m$ consecutive $O_1$'s in $N$ trials is
$P^{N}_{0,m}$.
This can be computed using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $P$.

EDIT:
For fixed $m$, the generating function of the sequence $P^{N}_{0,m}$ is
$$ g(x)= \sum_{N=0}^\infty P^{N}_{0,m} x^N = (I-xP)^{-1}_{0,m}$$
I  get
$$ \eqalign{g(x) &= \dfrac{p^m x^m}{1 - (2-p) x + (1-p)^2 \sum_{j=2}^m  p^{j-2} x^j + (1-p) p^{m-1} x^{m+1}}\cr  &= \dfrac{p^m x^m (1-p x)}
{(1-x)^2 + p^m (1-p) x^{m+1}(1-x)}}$$

This suggests the following recurrence method.  Let 
$$ \eqalign{a_0 &= \ldots = a_{m-1} = 0\cr
            a_m &= p^m \cr
            a_{m+1} &= (2-p) p^m\cr}$$
and for $j$ from $m+2$ to $N$ take
$$ a_j  = 2 a_{j-1} -a_{j-2} - p^m (1-p) (a_{j-m-1} - a_{j-m-2}) $$

Then your desired probability is $a_N$.
This is easily implemented in a spreadsheet.

EDIT:  If $N$ is very large, there may be difficulties involving precision.
Then you may want to use an asymptotic form of the result.  If we write 
$$d(x) =  1 - (2-p) x + (1-p)^2 \sum_{j=2}^m  p^{j-2} x^j + (1-p) p^{m-1} x^{m+1}$$
(the denominator of $g(x)$ in its first form)
and assuming its roots $r_1, \ldots, r_{m+1}$ are all distinct we have 
$$ g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} \dfrac{p^m r_i^m}{d'(r_i) (x - r_i)} $$
so that
$$ a_N = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} \dfrac{p^m}{d'(r_i) r_i^{N+1-m}} $$
The smallest root in absolute value is $1$, with $d'(1) = -p^m$, so $\lim_{N \to \infty} a_N = 1$ (which is obvious from the probabilistic formulation).
The next-smallest root in absolute value will determine how rapidly $a_N$ approaches $1$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Hi Robert, Can this be calculated. Is there a tool that I can use. As the numbers are large, I am looking for a tool where I can pass N, m and  p(success) and it gives me probability of (m or more consecutive successes).Will appreciate your help if you can

Comment: Thanks Robert, I will calculate $a_N$ and update the question. Though spreadsheets (excel) does not handle more than 64K rows, but This is doable easily otherwise.

Comment: Hi Robert, The calculated value is ~.2354. Does that mean, I have to do 4 experiments of N trials each in order to expect to see at least one string of m or more consecutive successes. Also, the value stopped increasing (within precision of my computer) somewhere before j = 600 million. That indicates increasing number of trials does not matter as much (in proportion). So, what would be the difference between 4 experiments of N each, or one experiment of 4N. N is not a factor in the formula except from range of j, which did not seem to matter after some time (~600 M)

Comment: Precision can be a serious issue with these computations if $N$ is very large.  For large $N$ it is better to use an asymptotic form.  I'll edit.

Comment: But in any case it's obvious that $a_N \to 1$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: What $m$ are you using in your example?

Comment: I am using N = 877646440,
m = 79279,
p = 6204/6205 (or 0.999838839645447....)

Comment: Could you please suggest a recurrence method for the easymptotic form the way you did earlier like - $$ \eqalign{a_0 &= \ldots = a_{m-1} = 0\cr}$$ I do not know how to get d' and $r_i$.

Comment: Accurate numerical computation for those values will be very difficult, I think.  There are lots of roots very close together.

Comment: OK, could you please see if it is any easier to figure this: N = 877646440, p(X) = 1/6205, p(Y) = 6204/6205. I want to know which one is expected more number of times - $(1)$ 2 Xs in a row, ($(p(X))^2$ = 1/38502025).  $(2)$ 79279 (or more) Ys in a row (p(Y) raised to power 79279 = roughly 1/360000). Which one's is expected more number of times and by how much? What would your intuition say.

Comment: Expected values are easy.  There are $N-1$ places to put two $X$'s in a row, $N-79278$ places to put $79278$ $Y$'s in a row, so the expected number of occurrences of two $X$'s in a row is $(N-1) p(X)^2 \approx 22.79481245$, and the expected number of occurrences of  $79279$ $Y$'s in a row is $(N-79278) p(Y)^{79279} = 2477.493508$.

Comment: Thanks. my expectation was similar. However, based upon above suggested recurrence, if I use p = 1/6205 and m = 2, the probability calculation approaches 1. If I use p = 6204/6205 and m = 79278, the probability calculation approaches .24. How to reconcile the fact that an outcome with higher probability is expected less number of times. Though while calculating probability i am using m or more. For calculating expected number, you used m (2 and 79278 respectively)

Comment: Actually you also used m or more in a way. So how to reconcile with probability vs expected number. To me, the expected number seems appropriate. Do we need to use a different method for probability calculation, Or an event with lower probability can really be expected to occur more number of times?

Comment: The probability in both cases approaches $1$ as $N \to \infty$.  In the case of $Y$, the events tend to come in bunches (if trials $k$ to $k+m-1$ are $Y$'s, it's highly likely that the next one is also a $Y$, so you also have trials $k+1$ to $k+m$).

Comment: Hi Robert, could you please point me to the source for the formula for expected number of strings of size m as you described on 18th Aug. i.e. expected number of $79279$ consecutive $Y$'s = $(N - 79278)p(Y)^{79279}$. I am looking for a standard reference like a book, or a website. I know it is simple logical, but a reference will help me. Thanks